# UserServiceDetails of Spring Security doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security, userdetailsservice

I'm learning Spring4 by reading .And now, I met a problem about the Spring Security.When I request "/home", I get the login page, but when I fill the form and submit it, I can't go into the UserDetailsService but go the controller directly and then back to the login page. I debug it and find the spitterUserDetailsService is not null, it is autowired.So I don't know what't the problem.Here is my code.Thanks in advance.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService spitterUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/spitter/login").permitAll()
           .and().rememberMe()
           .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/spitter/home").hasRole("SPITTER")
           .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(spitterUserDetailsService);
    }

}



@Service
public class SpitterUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private SpitterRepository spitterRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.err.println("---------- User Details Service start -----------");
        Spitter spitter = spitterRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(spitter == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " not found ");
        }
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_SPITTER"));
        System.out.println(spitter.getUsername() + " : ROLE_SPITTER");
        return new User(spitter.getUsername(), spitter.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

}



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spitter")
public class SpitterController {

    @Autowired
    private SpitterRepository spitterRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value= "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("spitter", new Spitter());
        return "spitter/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/loginForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("spitter") Spitter spitter){
        System.out.println(spitter.getUsername() + " logined..");
        return "redirect:home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("spitter", new Spitter());
        return "spitter/registerForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@ModelAttribute("spitter") Spitter spitter){
        spitterRepository.addSpitter(spitter);
        return "spitter/registerSuccessfully";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String hello(){
        return "spitter/helloWorld";
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is my github url : https://github.com/CherryYu/SpringHibernate.git

Comment: Which is what you told spring to do. Your form is posting to the controller directly and with that bypassing Spring Security...

Comment: I override the configure in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and define some rules.I don't know why my form posting to the controller directly... I just want  when I request "/home", I can verify the user's role by UserDetailsService.

Comment: Because that is what you are doing in your form. You should be posting the `/login` so that it is handled by Spring Security...

Comment: I guess, you need to declare somewhere that /* pattern needs to be intercepted by spring security config and has to be handled by SpitterUserDetailsService. what about /spitter/login and /spitter/home urls? do they also bypass spring security?

Comment: @Jayz   When I request /spitter/home, Spring Security seems work, it's back to login page.

Answer (score -1):

there's your fix. replace "/spitter/home" with "/*" in your SecurityConfig.configure method. you need spring security to intercept all requests except those to "/spitter/login".